# Good way to determine if someone left a webpage

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2005

I am trying to code an app for work where our clients can edit certain fields. When they click edit, the code will lock the data to be editted. And when they click save the data will unlock. But I am having trouble deciding if I can unlock the data when they click elsewhere, go to another page or site, or even close the browser.

What's a good way to decide if the user has left the edit page?

(We are using C# .NET 3.5 and JQuery and a SQL Server 2005 DB).

Comment: Where is this 'lock' happening? On the server??

Comment: In C# code I have a locks class that references a locks table in the database

Comment: IMHO your design is really bad - you should NEVER do this pessimistic locking in an interactive situation esp. with web applications... implement an optimistic strategy instead!

Comment: have you looked into the onClose listener?

Comment: @chris, first to say Yahia is right, but you can use onUserExit jQuery plugin to find out when page is closed, here is the example of code that ends a session on user exit : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10481972/351383

Comment: @yahia, what's the best approach to this then?

Comment: @chris http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

Comment: yeah i see it, as a requirement of the client i have to lock the code when a user clicks on edit (so if two people click on edit and change the same piece of data, we will lose one, which is unacceptable)

Comment: In that case you can store other piece of data to a new piece of data :)  I mean if both users edited for example "document 15", and had a collision, you can save one to a new for example : "document 15-copy"

Comment: and as per OCC it is used "When conflicts are rare, transactions can complete" and in my data they is high number of conflicts

Comment: the problem is that both users depend on what that piece of data is and we can only have one copy of "document 15", we work in statistics

Comment: @chris without more details about the requirements I can only recommend some optimistic strategy which could be combined with some sort of alert to the the second/third user either on edit and/or on save... another strategy employed is an algorithm common in collaboration software called "Operational Transformation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really must use pessimistic locking you could add check in Session_End and unlock all locks that this user set in current session. Use onUserExit jQuery plugin to end session if user closes the browser window or goes on another site, here is the example :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10481972/351383

Comment: Did you include onUserExit javascript ? Can you do that on this page http://www.userfirst.com/creations/onuserexit/

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of "onunload" event of html  tag. This event is raised 
- when Page is closed using X button
- when Page is redirected(In your case user clicks on edits and move on to different link without saving.)

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is being understood as "what's a good way to decide if the user has abandoned the edit page without having clicked 'Save' to unlock the field?"

> But I am having trouble deciding if I can unlock the data when they click elsewhere, go to another page or site, or even close the browser.

All the scenarios in which someone looks at another page from the same application might mean another window in the same session - perhaps to check something. You don't want that to trigger an unlock because your user could still have a window open in which they can submit the edit.

The other scenarios where the user leaves the page can use onUserExit.

However, you omit from this list the scenario "user goes to lunch leaving webpage open". This is why pessimistic locking is problematic.

Therefore, rephrase the problem as "the user has clicked Edit, but then failed to make the amendment and save within a reasonable time limit".

Basically, your lock should at some point expire.

Upon clicking 'Edit', the save lock kicks in and a timer (5 minutes?) starts, which is also visible on-screen. (If getting these in sync is an issue, make the client-side timer shorter than the server-side one). Your users must make the change and click Save within this time. You could perhaps add an Extend button to extend the time.

The principle is that you need to determine that someone has left it too long, not that someone has left it. You also show to users that having clicked Edit you are expecting them to make an edit some time soon.

You will need to code your system to unlock fields where the lock has expired.

This has the benefit that your countdown will look 'cool' to the sorts of people that request such edit locks.